# Matplotlib scatter plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, data-visualization, scatter-plot

```
plt.scatter(data_std[:, 1], data_std[:, 8], c=kmeans_3,s=30, cmap='rainbow')
plt.scatter(data_std[:, 2], data_std[:, 9], c=kmeans_3,s=30, cmap='rainbow')
plt.scatter(data_std[:, 3], data_std[:, 10], c=kmeans_3,s=30, cmap='rainbow')
plt.scatter(data_std[:, 4], data_std[:, 11], c=kmeans_3,s=30, cmap='rainbow')
plt.scatter(data_std[:, 5], data_std[:, 12], c=kmeans_3,s=30, cmap='rainbow')
plt.scatter(data_std[:, 6], data_std[:, 13], c=kmeans_3,s=30, cmap='rainbow')
plt.scatter(data_std[:, 7], data_std[:, 0], c=kmeans_3,s=30, cmap='rainbow')
#plt.label(kmeans)
#plt.title(k=3)

plt.show
##
plt.scatter(data_std[:, 1], data_std[:, 8], c=kmeans_4,s=30, cmap='rainbow')
plt.scatter(data_std[:, 2], data_std[:, 9], c=kmeans_4,s=30, cmap='rainbow')
plt.scatter(data_std[:, 3], data_std[:, 10], c=kmeans_4,s=30, cmap='rainbow')
plt.scatter(data_std[:, 4], data_std[:, 11], c=kmeans_4,s=30, cmap='rainbow')
plt.scatter(data_std[:, 5], data_std[:, 12], c=kmeans_4,s=30, cmap='rainbow')
plt.scatter(data_std[:, 6], data_std[:, 13], c=kmeans_4,s=30, cmap='rainbow')
plt.scatter(data_std[:, 7], data_std[:, 0], c=kmeans_4,s=30, cmap='rainbow')
plt.show()
```

For the above code, how can I plot two separate scatter plots in the same cell?

have checked the documentation and tried to find the solution elsewhere but unable to find help

Comment: Why don't you just split the code into two cells? By the way, you don't need `plt.show()` in a Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two subfigures and then use the respective axis objects for plotting. I am giving a sample answer. You can adapt it to your case

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)

ax1.scatter(data_std[:, 1], data_std[:, 8], c=kmeans_3,s=30, cmap='rainbow')
ax1.scatter(data_std[:, 2], data_std[:, 9], c=kmeans_3,s=30, cmap='rainbow')
ax1.set_title('k=3')
# ....

ax2.scatter(data_std[:, 1], data_std[:, 8], c=kmeans_4,s=30, cmap='rainbow')
ax2.scatter(data_std[:, 2], data_std[:, 9], c=kmeans_4,s=30, cmap='rainbow')
# ....

plt.show()
```